# What is the correct stored value for umlaut "ü" in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, diacritics

I would like to deliver UTF-8 websites with Perl directly. I ran into several encoding issues because the source data is not completely stored in UTF-8. Due to a debugging session for the encoding issues I discovered two different representations for the German umlaut `ü`. Which one is the correct stored value with Perl?

- `\xFC`, which is the Unicode position `U+00FC` for `ü`
- `0xC3 0xBC`, which is the UTF-8 hex representation for `ü`

If there isn't any difference then why is Perl storing umlauts in different representations and does not store it in either the Unicode position or the UTF-8 hex representation.

[Unicode/UTF-8 character table reference](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin)'s `fix_latin`.

```
$ perl -MEncoding::FixLatin=fix_latin -MEncode=encode_utf8 \
   -E'say sprintf "%v02X", encode_utf8(fix_latin("\xFC\xC3\xBC"))'
C3.BC.C3.BC
```

Internally, it's best to work with Unicode. Decode inputs, encode outputs. You likely got the mix forgetting to encode an output.

Comment: In conclusion `0xC3 0xBC` (UTF-8 hex) is the right representation. Thanks. `fix_latin` would help for for 50% of of the source data. I already have re-encoding method which uses `from_to` (from [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode)) to "UTF-8". I would end up use my re-encoding method covered in `fix_latin` to get valid UTF-8 data, right?

Comment: UTF-8 is the right output because you asked for UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "correct", they are different representations. Generally speaking, it would probably be better to settle on Unicode and printing it out as UTF-8, but the main complication is really to know exactly what you have at each step of processing; if you can use UTF-8 reliably throughout, maybe that's simpler in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are correct. It depends what your intentions are.

`\xFC` is the correct form of a string of Unicode text that contains the ü character. This is typically the form in which you process the string of text within your application.

`0xC3 0xBC` is the correct form of a string of bytes which encodes the ü character into UTF-8. This is typically the form in which you receive or transmit UTF-8 bytes from or to some external entity, such as a network socket or disk filehandle.